# How do we know which native or non-native token will be transferred when we call transfer()/send(), or use balanceOf inside token contract?

Tags: solidity, tokens

Let's say we have a non-native contract.
Whenever we call `transfer()/send()` or directly manipulate via `balanceOf`, **how do we know which token (either native or non-native token) will be transferred**?

I came across this from looking at [this](https://bscscan.com/bytecode-decompiler?a=0xe0d778341878da93d3d5bdc575667e4d40a3baba) scam contract's decompiled source code. Obviously I didn't see any import of `IERC20` or anything, or decompilation probably won't include them ?

Such decompiled code works with STPT token, and it's on BSC network. As I looked in the code, and transactions, I came to conclusion that `balanceOf` works against STPT token. **But how can we know this when looking at the code alone without checking elsewhere?**

As we have multiple ways to transfer as follows

- `payable(addr).transfer(amount)` - I knew this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68545930/how-to-withdraw-all-tokens-from-the-my-contract-in-solidity/68546566#68546566) that this is meant to transfer native token
- `transfer()` and `send()` - I believe the developer needs to know such that the variable that calls this method needs to be based upon `IERC20` or others ?
- `balanceOf()` - I'm not sure about this...

Please feel free to correct me, go in depths or link me articles to read more on this stuff. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The methods (payable address).transfer() or (payable address).send() inside a smart contract is about transfering the native coin of the blockchain from the smart contract to the defined (payable address). In Ethereum, it will transfer Ether. In BsC, it will transfer BNB.

Comment: Hey thanks! So if I just `address.transfer()` or `address.send()`, then always it means we transfer non-native token right? Because from my understanding, non-native token would have a separate contract.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by non-native token. If you are on ethereum, address.transfer() and address.send() will transfer Ether, always. =)

Comment: Non-native I mean non-ETH. I'm doubt `address.transfer()` and `address.send()` would always send Ether. What if such `address` is non-ETH, but another token contract.

Comment: No problem. I also got a confirmation in SCP group. So if I have ERC20 address, if use `address.transfer()` it will transfer such ERC20 token (not ETH). But if I want to transfer ETH to such address, then I will do just like your answer `payable(address).transfer()`. Thanks again!

Comment: I think they gave you the wrong answer. See, if you use (address).transfer you are transfering Ether, even if address is the account of a contract. You can send Ether for External Accounts and also to ERC20 Token accounts. When you have the instance of a smart contract which have a transfer function, then you can use (instance of the contract).transfer() to call the transfer function. Be aware of this difference. One thing is an address, other is the instance of a contract. The name of the function is the same, but only the name.